# How to find the optimal values of a dual problem.

Tags: proof-verification, linear-programming

So i have this question with this answer and I am not sure if the answer sheet is wrong.

[image]

I have no problems getting to the dual. However the answer sheet states that y1=18.75 and y2=26.25.

I get that y1=26.25 and y2=18.75

by rearranging the constraints of the dual

*y2*=45-*y1* and *y2*=150-*y1*

then 45-*y1*=150-*y1*

and y1= 26.25.

Am i correct and the answer sheet is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: One can see that the given solution is not correct since $18.75 + (0.2)26.25 = 24 < 30$.

Comment: so i am indeed correct ?

Comment: I can confirm that you´re right.